# userpro search is not working in jobera wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I use the jobera theme with userpro, but I have a little problem.
I know you don’t offer support for 3rd party plugins and stuff, but if you could help me I would be greatful, the problem is when I try to search in member directory, search button does not work.

Strange but it happens only with this theme.

Comment: which member directory? Could you please improve your question by providing more information and code?

Comment: userpro plugin member directory